# Как происходит ответ от сервера?

Tags: android

Приведу банальны пример про такси. Клиент заказывает такси и нажимает кнопку заказать, тут пошли данные на сервер и таксистом отправился заказ. Когда заказ принят ответ идет на сервер с данными о водителе или с чем они там приходят (не важно). Клиент получает ответ и смотрит информацию о водителе.

Как клиенту приходит ответ с информацией? Ведь там после отправки не сразу все происходит, какое то время заказ весит в ожидании пока его примут а затем приходят данные с информации конкретному клиенту когда заказ принят.

Как сделать похожую штуку, может материал есть на эту тему или еще что посоветуете почитать.

Comment: GCM и иже с ним

Comment: Стоит погуглить такую штуку, как longpoll

Comment: GCM  или WebSocket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно такой функционал делается через Socket или WebSocket.

Таким образом к одному и тому же серверу подрубаются сокетным подключением и все таксисты и все клиенты.

Соответственно все подключенные к серверу могут как слать информацию к нему, так и получать от него данные.

То есть:

Клиент отправил запрос на такси через сокет. Сервер обработал запрос, передал теми же сокетами информацию о заказе всем таксистам в указанной области. 
Таксист увидел заказ, нажал согласится на заказ и отправил запрос на сервер о принятии заказа. Сервер увидел запрос от таксиста и передал информацию о нем клиенту. Клиент отловил это в приложении, UI обновилось и информация о таксисте видна клиенту. При этом пока заказ не принят таким же образом по таймеру таксист может предоставлять данные клиенту о своем местоположении, например.

[Можно глянуть простейший пример.](http://www.javatpoint.com/socket-programming)

В более сложных вариантах лучше создавать отдельный поток под каждое сокетное подключение, использовать БД на сервере для сохранения каких-то постоянных данных и так далее.